# passing rest args to next func and args is different now

Tags: javascript

This is the code

```js
const func0 = (...args) => {
  console.error('-------0-------');
  console.error(args);
  console.error(args.length);
  func1(args);
}

const func1 = (...args) => {
  console.error('-------1-------');
  console.error(args);
  console.error(args.length);
}

func0(1, 2, 3);
```

why the 2nd arg is different now, how to make it the same as 1st one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(...args) =>` in the parameter list transforms the arguments into an *array* named `args`. So when you call `func1(args);`, you're calling `func1` with *one* argument, an argument that's an array (whereas `func0` was called with *three* arguments).

If you wanted to call `func1` with the three original arguments, use *spread* to transform the `args` array into a parameter list:

```js
const func0 = (...args) =>  {
    console.error('-------0-------');
    console.error(args);
    console.error(args.length);
    func1(...args);
}

const func1 = (...args) => {
    console.error('-------1-------');
    console.error(args);
    console.error(args.length);
}

func0(1,2,3);
```